# Java : Volatile variable access

Tags: java, volatile, non-volatile

I am a little confuse about how volatile variable effectively accesses from "main" memory. How's it different from a variable (non-volatile) that has a local copy ? What's the typical workflow whenever multiple threads accesses a non-volatile **vs** a volatile variable ? I mean how do they work behind the scene ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Volatile keyword in Java - Clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603157/volatile-keyword-in-java-clarification)

Comment: I wasn't that clear after reading that thread, so I opened this question. i am actually asking more about the workflow and memory access instead of the concept itself

Comment: Sorry for that offtop but I think it is worth to mention that one of advantage of `volatile` is that it also ensure *atomic reading* of primitives. It is useful in case of 64bits variables (like `long` or `double`) on 32 bits processors machines because they prevent updating variable between reading first 32 and last 32 bits of variable.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. 64-bit numeric variables (double and long) that are not declared volatile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have a variable that can be accessed by multiple threads.

Thread 1 looks at the variable. Because looking at shared memory is more expensive than thread-local memory, it makes a copy of the variable. (Note that an object won't be copied, just its reference.)

Thread 2 looks at the same variable. It decides to change the variable. But Thread 1 doesn't know it! Thread 1 is still using stale data. This is a Very Bad Thing. By making it `volatile`, each thread must look at the original variable when accessing it. They aren't permitted to make local copies, so it won't get stale.

Comment: by saying shared memory you mean Heap ? and thread-local memory means the Stack on each Thread ? and where does that copy of variable go ?

Comment: where it goes physically is up to the implementation of the JVM. We don't know or care where it goes. All we know is that threads are allowed to cache variables, but if they're volatile, they can't.

Comment: Ok what if I use Lock instead of Volatile ? is it going to be like thread make a copy of the variable on its local stack, and it updates that variable (mutable) to the shared memory once it exits the lock, so that the next thread will always see the most updated value ?

Comment: if you use a lock instead of a volatile, then you can guarantee that no one else overwrites your value while you're using it. For example, if in a given method you had to use its value four times, if halfway through the method some other thread changes your variable, that's bad. But if you don't need to use it in that fashion, then a lock is overkill.

Comment: Correct I understand the concept. I just want to clarify and confirm about how does each thread set the value back to the shared memory once it exits the lock so that the next incoming thread will see that latest value.

Comment: There's no guarantee that after you exit your lock on one thread that the other thread will actually read the new value. It might be perfectly content to use its old value for as long as it feels necessayr.

Comment: I thought we use LOCK just to make sure one thread can access the given method at a time and update the value, and when it exits the next one can enter and see the latest, no ?

Comment: If Thread 1 locks, gets the value, sets the value, and releases, then Thread 2 does the same, Thread 1 has every right to skip over reading the value because it doesn't know it has changed. It's a fundamental flaw in the memory model, which is why the volatile keyword exists.